# no member named 'isinf' in the global namespace

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors

I'm having problems compiling pretty much anything on my Mac (including for example xgboost), suggesting that the problem isn't with individual projects but with something that's wrong on my machine. Others in my team can compile things fine.

When I try and compile, I get errors like:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:317:9: error: no member named 'isinf' in the global namespace
using ::isinf;
```

all are problems in `cmath`.

I have:

- Checked that `cmake` is up to date.
- Completely removed and reinstalled Command Line Tools using `xcode-select --install`
- Completely remove XCode and run `sudo xcode-select --reset`
- Compared my `make configure` output with a coworker - it is identical, as are all versions of all tools/libraries
- Checked for anything in `brew` that looks problematic - can't see anything. Brew doctor says I'm ready to brew (everything is fine).
- Check my MacOS SDK is ok, it is (10.15)

Any issues on GitHub or here that I've found don't have an answer that points to the root cause of the issue.

What is going on here? At the very least, where can I look for more clues?

Comment: Sounds like your library installation is borked.  `<cmath>` generally includes `<math.h>` and then uses those `using ::name` to import the names from `<math.h>` into the `std` namespace. Not sure how you'd go about checking or fixing that on a mac.

Comment: FWIW for most common packages you can just install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) and then e.g. `brew install xgboost`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know, but it is a very common practice and AFAIK libc++ and libstdc++ both use it.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I've reinstalled/reset CommandLineTools, which is how you typically go about fixing problems like these, but so far no luck :(

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use the CommandLineTools SDK rather than the XCode.app SDK. Running "xcode-select --reset" will make the macOS fallback to use the XCode.app SDK.

```
#Check the current sdk
xcrun --show-sdk-path

#Change sdk
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools          #Using CommandLineTools SDK
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer   #Using XCode.app SDK
```

Comment: This answer could probably use a bit more explanation of why using the CommandLineTools SDK will help in this scenario, this will help the answer remain useful into the future, even if some of the specifics, like the command-line switches, change.